# Why is Proof of non-inclusion in a Merkle Tree harder than Proof of inclusion?

Tags: merkle-damgaard, hash-tree

I am new to cryptography and I am wondering Why is Proof of non-inclusion in a Merkle Tree harder than Proof of inclusion?

My naive thought for Proof of non-inclusion is that I would look for inclusion and if doesn't exist it is not included isn't it? I know this is wrong because I see papers on sparse Merkle trees etc but I couldn't figure out where my thought has a flaw? Can anyone explain preferably with less notation?

Comment: If exist you simply give the data and it can be verified. If it doesn't' exist, how it can be verified? Maybe you are not giving the data?

Comment: Ahhh got it now! Dummy me